# When should we be concerned about Disk I/O?

Tags: sql-server, disk

Our web application handles a large number of concurrent requests for 8 hours a day. At this time the disk I/O (specifically on the tempdb database log file) goes up to 470 reads-writes per second, as per the Performance Monitor. When this number goes above 500 the Performance Monitor labels the disk as busy. But the disk used is high performance SSD drives rated to handle upto 5000 IOPS, hosted on AWS.

So my question is the disk ok with upto 500 reads-writes per second for upto 8 hours?

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to change your approach to the matter and start looking at IO related numbers within SQL Server first, metrics like IO latency.

SQL Server collects this information for you by default, if you see large latencies in SQL Server then move on to Server and start collecting the Performance counters and other things.

No number is too good or too bad without considering the circumstances like the disk type, work load etc.

I would recommend that, first of all make sure you are following all the best practices where ever possible, things like:

1. A dedicated drive for the Tempdb.
2. Multiple data files (4-8 is usually a good number) for your tempdb.
3. Have Trace Flags 1118 and 1117 enabled.
4. A dedicated drive for data files for all the databases.
5. A dedicated drive for log files for all the databases.
6. Auto-growth set to a healthy number of MB instead of default 10%.
7. And a few other things, simply google it and you will find a lot of stuff online.

Once you have your databases setting set as defined in best practices then start looking at IO latency for each drive, using SQL Server DMVs. A query I usually use to check latency is:

```
SELECT tab.[Drive], tab.volume_mount_point AS [Volume Mount Point], 
    CASE 
        WHEN num_of_reads = 0 THEN 0 
        ELSE (io_stall_read_ms/num_of_reads) 
    END AS [Read Latency],
    CASE 
        WHEN num_of_writes = 0 THEN 0 
        ELSE (io_stall_write_ms/num_of_writes) 
    END AS [Write Latency],
    CASE 
        WHEN (num_of_reads = 0 AND num_of_writes = 0) THEN 0 
        ELSE (io_stall/(num_of_reads + num_of_writes)) 
    END AS [Overall Latency],
    CASE 
        WHEN num_of_reads = 0 THEN 0 
        ELSE (num_of_bytes_read/num_of_reads) 
    END AS [Avg Bytes/Read],
    CASE 
        WHEN num_of_writes = 0 THEN 0 
        ELSE (num_of_bytes_written/num_of_writes) 
    END AS [Avg Bytes/Write],
    CASE 
        WHEN (num_of_reads = 0 AND num_of_writes = 0) THEN 0 
        ELSE ((num_of_bytes_read + num_of_bytes_written)/(num_of_reads + num_of_writes)) 
    END AS [Avg Bytes/Transfer]
FROM (SELECT LEFT(UPPER(mf.physical_name), 2) AS Drive, SUM(num_of_reads) AS num_of_reads,
             SUM(io_stall_read_ms) AS io_stall_read_ms, SUM(num_of_writes) AS num_of_writes,
             SUM(io_stall_write_ms) AS io_stall_write_ms, SUM(num_of_bytes_read) AS num_of_bytes_read,
             SUM(num_of_bytes_written) AS num_of_bytes_written, SUM(io_stall) AS io_stall, vs.volume_mount_point 
      FROM sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats(NULL, NULL) AS vfs
      INNER JOIN sys.master_files AS mf WITH (NOLOCK)
      ON vfs.database_id = mf.database_id AND vfs.file_id = mf.file_id
      CROSS APPLY sys.dm_os_volume_stats(mf.database_id, mf.[file_id]) AS vs 
      GROUP BY LEFT(UPPER(mf.physical_name), 2), vs.volume_mount_point) AS tab
ORDER BY [Overall Latency];
```

The number you should be looking at to start with is the `Overall Latency`, considering it is an SSD your overall latency should be less than 5 ideally. But even if it is more than 5 it is not necessarily a bad number.

Again it depends on the work load. If a lot of queries are hitting tempdb (which shouldn't really happen in an OLTP database) then maybe you need to start looking at your code and try to optimise queries that are hitting tempdb a lot.

Long story short instead of looking at the Performance counters first and then trying to figure out whether it is a problem or not why not ask SQL Server first that what is bothering it the most and try to fix that first :)

Even though my answer looks very long for a very short question but trust me there is a lot to be done and a lot to be considered before you reach any conclusion. My advice will be to read on how SQL Server metrics can be collected and how they can be used to translate into real conclusions.

No one metric alone can conclude an issue or fix an issue, it is an enterprise application and you will need to look a lot of things in their context to draw a meaningful conclusion. Hope this helps.

Comment: UV from me, but I'd link to some blogs on your bullet points since I doubt the OP would know why he needs a dedicated drive (ideally SSD), more than one data file, etc.

Comment: M.Ali - Thanks for your input! I have been using DMV queries to get other metrics, but was not quite sure which one would be useful to measure any disk pressure. I think I may have used sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats, and not seen any alarming numbers. But I will try again today!  I actually have implemented many of your suggestions - (1) I have 8 temp db data files (2) Data files for tempdb and application db are on 1 drive (3) Log files for tempdba nd application db are on another drive. (4) I have tried setting Trace Flags 1117 and 1118. (5) Autogrowth is set to 300MB.

Comment: @SGK , your'e welcome, starting point should be Overall Latency, if the number is acceptable then move on to other metrics but if it is a big number, then dig deeper and find out what causing the overall latency, either it is writes or reads etc.

Comment: @M.Ali - We have this stored proc that gets called by each user every 3 seconds. And this stored proc does create table variables and table valued sql functions - which is what creates the temp tables on the tempdb, and causes tempdb logging is my guess. I am trying to eliminate the use of some of these temp tables, but due to the logic I do need some of them.

Comment: I think you have misread my suggestions, I suggested to have a dedicated drive for tempdb (data and log file), put this on the fastest possible drive, SSD or Fusions IO drives. Also instead of using 300MB use 256MB or 512MB (the right bit calculation number) for the file increments size.

Comment: Wowwww a proc getting called every 3 seconds by every user creating temp tables,,,,, OUCH!!!!! you need to change the logic and get rid of the Temp tables from that proc also make sure you are only using Inline Table valued functions and not Multi-statement table valued function. I think you know the culprit, you just need to do something about it :) stop looking around at other innocent things in your sql server :)

Comment: Both the drives used for the data files and log files are high performance SSD drives. The only thing missing is that the TempDB is not on a separate drive. I will need to see if I can permission for 2 more drives - 1 for TempDB data files and 1 for TempDB log files. This App is hosted on AWS. Do you think that would negatively impact the disk capability? since its being shared for possible other tenants?

Comment: I know this stored proc is the culprit and that the tempdb log file is the one getting pounded. We have started work on re-architecting the system. But for now it HAS to continue working this way, and I cant change the stored proc much. I did change one of the multi statement sql fns to an inline fn, but that did not bring down the IO. But I may have been looking at the wrong metric. Today I'll test using your query.

Comment: Unfortunately our AWS load testing server is going to be unavailable for another week, so I cannot test. But once I do I will let you know. I ran the query on our local DEV server, and the overall latency is 9 (Its not an SSD drive). Is that bad? Until what value would you consider it to be acceptable?